# How to make a sql query on among two tables join include group by and max value

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables, `coaches` and `awardscoaches`. `coaches` gives me the the relationship between coaches and team. `awardscoaches` includes the coach award informcation. Below is their structure:

**coaches**

```
coachid: string   (the id of each coach, it is the primary key in this table)
tmid:    string   (the team id)
```

**awardscoaches**

```
coachid: string   (the id of each coach)
award:   string   (the award the coach got, each coach may have more than one award, so the primary key in this table is the combine of coachid and award)
```

now I am going to write a query to find out for each team which coach had most awards.

below is the sql I am currently have:

```
select c.tmid tmid, max(a.count) count from coaches c 
inner join (select coachid, count(award) count 
from awardscoaches group by coachid) a 
on a.coachid = c.coachid group by c.tmid;
```

this query will return the maximum number of award in each team. but I am not sure how to select the coachid in the result set since I can only select the field from the group by. 
I am looking for a general sql statement to achieve this requirement.

I tried below command:

```
select coachid,tmid,award_count 
from (select coachid,tmid,award_count
      ,rank() over(partition by tmid order by award_count desc) as rnk
      from (select a.coachid, count(*) over(partition by a.coachid) as award_count,c.tmid 
            from awardscoaches a
            join coaches c on c.coachid=a.coachid
           ) t
      ) t
where rnk = 1
```

but got duplicate lines as below:

```
murrabr01c  WAS 17
murrabr01c  WAS 17
murrabr01c  WAS 17
murrabr01c  WAS 17
krommbo01c  WIJ 10
krommbo01c  WIJ 10
krommbo01c  WIJ 10
krommbo01c  WIJ 10
wattto01c   WIN 7
wattto01c   WIN 7
wattto01c   WIN 7
```

Comment: mysql or hive? don't tag multiple.

Comment: sorry, it is hive

Comment: This is a faq, which you should find by googling your title & other brief phrasings of your question, except right now your post doesn't actually contain an intelligible phrasing of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
max(struct(a.cnt,a.coachid)).col2   as coachid
```

---

```
select      c.tmid                              as tmid
           ,max(struct(a.cnt,a.coachid)).col2   as coachid 

from                    coaches c 

            join       (select      coachid
                                   ,count(*)    as cnt

                        from        awardscoaches 

                        group by    coachid
                        ) a 

            on          a.coachid = 
                        c.coachid 

group by    c.tmid
;
```

Comment: I see `max(struct(a.cnt,a.coachid)).col2` is the key.